# Facing issue at Instascan Library in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular9, instascan

I have imported **instascan** library in **Index.html** file ,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"> </script>
```

I have code in my app.component.html as below,

```
<video id="preview"></video>
```

I have code in my app.component.ts as below,

```
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({                                                           
 video: document.getElementById('preview'),                                                    
 mirror: false,
 facingMode: { exact: 'environment' }});

 Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(cameras => {
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
        this.scanner.start(cameras[1]);
    } else {
        alert("Camera Permission denied");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    window.location.reload();
})
```

Facing issue in **Instascan**, its giving error as below while compiling,
     **Cannot find name 'Instascan'**.

Comment: Have you imported the `Instascan` module into your app component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `import` syntax instead of using `link` tag.

First, install Instascan NPM package:

```
npm i instascan
```

Then import it in your component:

```js
import Instascan from 'instascan';
...
```

Rest of your code will work.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help but after doing this i got the compilation error like "ERROR in ./node_modules/instascan/src/zxing.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs', can you help me out?

Comment: @AniketPatil There's the same issue on Github. Hope it helpful.  https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/95

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `javascript` library. If you want to use in component so you need to `declare` it on after `Import`. Like this ...

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var Instascan: any;
```

And If this `javascript` library useing `jQuatry` then also you `declare` `$`

```
declare var $: any;
```